# Use HTML data attribute in jQuery appended div

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm creating a simple portfolio layout for a client of mine and I want to be able to dynamically embed a Vimeo video into a div that is appended via jQuery using HTML data attributes

Below is my HTML markup with the Vimeo video ID stored as `data-video`

```
<div class="grid-block" data-video="32001208">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/225/125"/>
</div>
```

And this is my current jQuery snippet that appends a div with a class of `video` once the `grid-block` element is clicked.

```
$( ".grid-block" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).append( "<div class='video'>" );
});
```

What I want to be able to do is embed an iframe in this `video` div that shows a Vimeo video, with the `data-video` attribute above being the video ID.

This would be the Vimeo embed code with the video ID replaced with `XXXXXXX`;

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/XXXXXXXX?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=bc2026" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I hope that was clear and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not use the [data api](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to access the value of the `data-*` attribute

```
$(".grid-block").click(function () {
    $(this).append('<div class="video"><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/' + $(this).data('video') + '?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=bc2026" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
});
```